# Using 2D image to create 3D maze

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there any method to transform given image to 3D maze using three.js libraries? I was thinking about `heightmap`, but it does not seem like a perfect idea for this to work.

Thank you in advance.

[image: maze map]

Comment: No, [`heightmap`](http://danni-three.blogspot.com/2013/09/threejs-heightmaps.html) is right